# Passing a pointer to a 1D Fortran array to C++ with C_LOC() causes garbage values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to know the proper way to pass array from Fortran to C. It returns out that iso_c_binding only has C_F_pointer but no F_C_pointer. I tried to use c_loc, but I got -6.04639e-264 for the second element.

My Fortran code is:

```
SUBROUTINE SIMULATION(ARRAY) BIND(C)
    USE ISO_C_BINDING
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE (c_ptr), INTENT(INOUT) :: ARRAY
    REAL (C_DOUBLE), TARGET, SAVE :: ETA(0:1)

    ! Allocate an array and make it available in C
    ARRAY = C_LOC(ETA)
    ETA(0) = 1.0
    ETA(1) = 2.0

END SUBROUTINE SIMULATION
```

And my C++ code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    void simulation(double* array[]);
}
int main()
{
    double* array[2];
    simulation(array);
    cout << *array[0] << endl;
    cout << *array[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the the Fortran code is correct but you should not pass `array` in C++,,but better wait for a C++ guy to confirm.

Comment: Can some C or C++ guy explain to me difference of `double *array[10]` and `double (*array)[10]`? Or is it the same? The former array of pointers? Don't let a dumb fortranner answer this using a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure it is a problem with pointers in your C++ code. The Fortran code is correct.

This works well:

```
extern "C" {
    void simulation(double  **array);
}
int main()
{
    double *array = NULL;
    simulation(&array);
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    cout << array[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Version with a pointer to fixed size array is in the end

```
extern "C" {
    void simulation(double (**array)[2]);
}
int main()
{
    double (*array)[2] = NULL;
    simulation(&array);
    cout << (*array)[0] << endl;
    cout << (*array)[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For me personally this is really difficult and confusing syntax with too many * and [] in the right combination. Some typedef would probably simplify it. Perhaps:

```
typedef double (*array2)[2];

extern "C" {
    void simulation(array2* array);
}

int main()
{
    array2 array;
    simulation(&array);
    cout << (*array)[0] << endl;
    cout << (*array)[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice, than in all three cases there is `simulation(&array);`. That means you must pass a pointer to the array pointer in order to be able to modify the array pointer.